# Jquery dialog to open multiple windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make system of multiple dialogs in one page using jquery dialog...

Functions looks like...

```
 function open_w(id){

         $('.opened').dialog('close');
         $(id).addClass('opened');
         $(id).dialog({position: 'center',  modal:true, width: '750px' });
           };


     function close_w(){
     $('.opened').dialog('close');
     $('.opened').removeClass('opened');
      };
```

As you see passing the ID opens me that windows, but before open close me old windows.. When i open it fist time everything is good.. But Next time it's doesn't want open

Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to re-create the dialog, instead of this every time:

```
$(id).dialog({position: 'center',  modal:true, width: '750px' });
```

You need to call `open` (on the *already* created dialog), like this:

```
$(id).dialog('open');
```

For example:

```
function open_w(id){
  close_w();
  $(id).addClass('opened')
       .dialog({position: 'center',  modal:true, width: '750px' })
       .dialog('open');
}
function close_w() {
  $('.opened').dialog('close').removeClass('opened');
}
```